# What happens to the Turkish Referendum if voter fraud concerns are sustained?

Tags: voting, turkey, turkish-referendum-2017

So the 2017 Turkish Referendum passed, but narrowly and with [some controversy](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/polls-open-in-turkeys-historic-referendum-on-reforms/2017/04/16/9496d2d8-225a-11e7-bb59-a74ccaf1d02f_story.html)

> Turkish President Recep Tayyip Erdogan won a historic referendum Sunday that will greatly expand the powers of his office, although opposition parties questioned the outcome and said they would challenge the results.

Of particular concern is this

> “There are those who are belittling the result. They shouldn’t try, it will be in vain,” [Erdogan] said. “It’s too late now.”

The objections are

> “The Supreme Electoral Board changed rules mid-game, after the ballot envelopes were opened, in a way contrary to laws,” said Kemal Kilicdaroglu, head of the main opposition People’s Republican Party. Earlier, the party’s vice chairman, Erdal Aksunger, said it would challenge between 37 percent and 60 percent of the ballot boxes and accused Anadolu’s results of being inaccurate.

The rule change was [explained here](http://news.sky.com/story/turkey-referendum-exit-poll-shows-majority-back-more-powers-for-president-10839890)

> A statement on the electoral board's website hours before polls closed said it would count ballots that had not been stamped by officials as valid, unless they could be proved fraudulent.
>
> That triggered strong criticism from the main opposition People's Republican Party (CHP), which said the decision caused a serious legitimacy problem in the referendum.

So what happens if the opposition gets proof of vote tampering? Given Erdogan's statements, and [recent consolidation of military power following the failed coup](http://www.nbcnews.com/storyline/turkey-military-coup/analysis-erdogan-s-purge-coup-proof-turkey-s-military-may-n630791), could anyone force Erdogan to not exercise that power?

Comment: No. And the state of emergency has been extended for three more months.